# ORDER BY timestamp with NULLs between future and past

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I would like to order SQL results by a timestamp field in descending order with newest entries first. However, I have certain rows that are blank or contain zeros. How can I sandwich these result in between future and past rows? Can this be done with CASEs?

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY when DESC
```

EDIT: Thanks to all the responses. Just so everyone knows, I went with MySQL's IFNULL, i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY IFNULL(when,UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) DESC
```

This was the simplest approach, where if when contained NULL the select query replaced it with the current unix time. Note that I updated my DB and replaced all 0s with NULL values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE IF(mytime is null, [sometime],mytime) ORDER BY ...
```

Not 100% sure whether 'is null' is the code, but I've done something similar.

Comment: So basically if it's NULL (or zero, or whatever) I should assign it the current time... which would put it in the middle with a simple DESC sort.

Comment: `IS NULL` is correct. Then you can replace `[sometime]` with `NOW()` to use the current time.

Comment: @user984512, updating the values in the table (and the future ones by setting a default, etc) is different from setting NULLs between past and future.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest version should be:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
ORDER  BY (mytime > now() AND mytime IS NOT NULL) DESC -- future times first
         ,(mytime IS NULL OR mytime = 0) DESC          -- NULL and "zero" next
         ,mytime DESC;                                 -- everything descending
```

Or even simpler with a CASE statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
ORDER  BY CASE WHEN mytime IS NULL OR mytime = 0 THEN now() ELSE mytime END DESC;
```

`FALSE` sorts before `TRUE`, therefore we need `DESC` to sort the hits first.
Read about the [special value "Zero" in MySQL in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-types.html).

Comment: Thank you for that "FALSE sorts before TRUE", "mytime IS NULL" solved my problem :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT   *
         , COALESCE(when, '2011-01-01 00:00:00') as new_when
FROM     table
ORDER BY new_when DESC
```

More about [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce). Basically I'm using `2011-01-01 00:00:00` as the default timestamp if one is not set, so any items with `null` will be treated as that date. We alias that date as `new_when` and order by that.

Comment: Nice, but two weaknesses: fails to treat "now" dynamically, fails to observe "zero" as requested.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this syntax works but I think this is the idea...

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN mytime IS NOT NULL AND mytime > NOW() THEN 'a'
         WHEN mytime IS NULL THEN 'b'
         WHEN mytime IS NOT NULL AND mytime < NOW() THEN 'c'
    END
    , mytime
```